# not able to render adaptive card in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, react-hooks, adaptive-cards

I am using npm package adaptivecards to render adaptive cards in react provided by microsoft.

When I try to render adaptive card, I am getting html document as object. When I try to render it, I am getting error `react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`.

How can I render html document if it is a type object?

The documentation I am following can be found at [here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards)

I am looking forward for your kind support.

Edits:

Problem now facing:

The card renders properly but  `adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function (action) { alert("Ow!"); }` not working. What to pass inside function parameters

```
import * as AdaptiveCards from "adaptivecards";
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [cardData, setCardData] = useState()

  useEffect(()=>{
    var card = {
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "version": "1.0",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "url": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/adaptive-card-50.png"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Hello Adaptive Cards!"
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
          "title": "Learn more",
          "url": "https://adaptivecards.io"
        },
        {
          "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
          "title": "GitHub",
          "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards"
        }
      ]
    };
  
    var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
  
    adaptiveCard.hostConfig = new AdaptiveCards.HostConfig({
      fontFamily: "Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif"
    });
  
    adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function (action) { alert("Ow!"); }
  
    adaptiveCard.parse(card);
  
    var renderedCard = adaptiveCard.render();
    // console.log(renderedCard)
  
    setCardData(renderedCard)

  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <div>{cardData}</div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `cardData` is an HTMLDivElement (as the error message says), so to render that inside a React app, you need `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: cardData?.innerHTML }}></div>` A better solution is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adaptivecards (see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-turing-flq1t?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @ChrisG can you please answer the solution in the post. Then I can upvote your answer.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Because I just tried it again and all the events don't work any longer.

Comment: I guess `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: cardData?.innerHTML }}></div>` is causing such behaviours.

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to insert the DOMElement using a ref. I've updated the sandbox.

Comment: hey! thanks @ChrisG. now, its working fine

Comment: I am facing same problem--card renders but onExecuteAction does not work.  I think the codesandbox link has changed?  I see starwars character demo, and not adaptive cards example.

Did you end up using the react package or were you able to get the execute to work using ref alternative?  (please share example)

Comment: Hey! @matt the solution worked and the code sandbox has been changed. But I can provide you the solution fine if you are still looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes please @NinjaTS!!  Can you share?

Comment: @NinjaTS, 

Ninja or Chris---can you guys share an example of getting javascript AdaptiveCards to render with React, where the action buttons work?  I understand there is a trick to using "ref" to wire the events up in the DOM.

Comment: here's a link to the example code `https://ibb.co/vvKvnKs`